# Careers Linkedin import: Internal Server Error

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linkedin

The `$.getJSON` call to `/import/linkedin-auth/:ID` fails, and the `GET` to `http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/import/linkedin-auth/:ID` returns `500 Internal Server Error`.

Something must be wrong! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi asymmetric, we made a change which (I believe) will fix the issue. Would you try it again?

Comment: 500 InternalServerError when import linkedin profile by sending  the request http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/cv/updatesection/78171. Any idea?